# Hammer js get DOM object where event was attached

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, hammer.js

I started to use Hammer JS for touch and swipe gestures.
As described in documentation `event.target` returns DOM object, where tap or press were initiated, but in my case I need whole dome object where event was attached.

For example, if I have DOM structure like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="title">Test Title</div>
  <div class="content">Some content<div>
</div>
```

and I attach event to whole `.wapper` object, when tap will initiated on `.title` element, `event.target` will return `.title`, not `.wrapper`

So how to catch not target but whole wrapper, where event attached?

Comment: I know this question is kind of old, but did you ever get it answered?

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't handle tap event properly and changed it with click. I use Hammer for swipe events only.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your reply :)